# Pandas read_sql_query -> to_string. remove spaces between columns (FWF)

Tags: pandas, pandasql

I am trying to create a fixed width file output in Pandas.  When using pandas dataFrames to_string all the data has a "white space" separating the values.  How do I remove the white space between the data columns?

```
    sql = """SELECT 
                FIELD_1,
                FIELD_2,
                .........
            FROM 
                VIEW"""
    db_connection_string = "your connection string"                                                                          
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=sql, con=db_connection_string)
    df['field_1'] = df['field_1'].str.pad(width=10, side='right', fillchar='-')
    df['field_2'] = df['field_2'].str.pad(width=10, side='right', fillchar='-')
    print(df.to_string(header=False, index=False)
```

I expected the following:

```
field1----field2----
```

What I got was:

```
 field1---- field2----
```

Please note the spaces between the columns.  This is what I am trying to remove.  The fields should be flush against one another and not have a whitespace separator.

Comment: The below code prints to a file my expected results.  Was hoping to_string would be able to do the same somehow?      
  
  
`f = open("test.txt", "w")
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        f.write(row['field_1'])
        f.write(row['field_2'] + "\n")
    f.close()`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is `to_string` add default separator. Possible solutions is join together all columns:

```
print(df.astype(str).apply(''.join, 1).to_string(header=False, index=False))
 field1----field_2---
```

Or only some columns:

```
print ((df['field_1'] + df['field_2']).to_string(header=False, index=False)))
```

Comment: So I used field_1, field_2 as an example and there are 10 total fields.  When I modify your awesome suggestion now I am getting the output as follows:  
field1----field2----...
  
The three dots on the end are new and now other fields show up after that?  Thanks for your help to date!

Comment: `print(df.astype(str).apply(''.join, 1).to_string(header=False, index=False))` not working? And if need write to file `df.astype(str).apply(''.join, 1).to_csv(filename, header=False, index=False)`

Comment: using to_csv writes all the fields / values properly however each row begins with a double quote and ends with a double quote!  Pandas really needs a to_fwf haha.  Getting closer!